# create a django form object and save it

Tags: python, django

I have a Signup form object which I'm using to create a signup page. Now I'm trying to add guest user feature to the app.  so I want to create a user account automatically when the user visits a page.  I'm trying to create the form object in the backend, populate it and call the save method explicitly. but I couldn't find a way to populate the fields from the backend.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: From where are you gathering the data with which to populate the form?

Comment: there are totally three fields in the form.  name, phone_number and email , I'm generating some placeholder  values for populating the form.  I have the data with me. how can I populate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a model instance (in this case a `User`) in a view from data that doesn't come from some POST or GET data, then don't use forms, but rather the model's API.

For instance the `User` class provides this helper function (example taken from the documentation) :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
```

More details here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

and here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user

This works for any model class. You can use is to create your guest user dynamically if you don't know the client, while you would log him/her otherwise.

The part when you decide whether you know a client or not is actually interesting but I think it's out of this question's scope.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you can create a dictionary of form_data, and then instantiate the form passing in the dict.

```
form_data = { "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key3": val3}
form = MyForm(data=form_data)
```

You could do this in the form_valid() method if you are using class-based views.